# Display image in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js

So, I am trying to present an image that is saved in MSSQL in a database that is already made by someone else.

Originally the column is of the IMAGE type, using Sequelize I converted to varbinary(MAX). Yes, I lost the data but it was for testing only

Then I inserted the image again and tried to show it on my fotos.handlebars.

And that was the result:

[printResult.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4EcB.png)

Is there any way to make the image appear instead of these characters?

My code:

**Model Fotos.JS:**

```js
const db = require('./db')

const Fotos = db.sequelize.define('Fotos', {
    COD_PESSOA:{
        type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    Sequencia:{
        type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    Foto:{
        type: db.Sequelize.BLOB
    },
    Padrao:{
        type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false
})

module.exports = Fotos
//Fotos.sync({force: true})
```

**fotos.handlebars:**

```html
<h1>Fotos:</h1>

{{#each fotos}}

    <h2>{{dataValues.Foto}}</h2>
    <hr>

{{/each}}
```

**app.js:**

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const Fotos = require('./models/Fotos')


//template engine
    app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}))
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

//body-parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())


//Rotas
    app.use('/fotos', (req, res)=>{
       //res.send('teste rota')
       
         Fotos.findAll().then((fotos)=>{
            res.render('fotos', {fotos: fotos})
        }).catch((erro)=>{
            res.send(erro)
        })
        
    })


    app.listen(8081, ()=>{
        console.log('Servidor Rodando')
    })
```

Comment: Hi Lucas! I don't know how handlebars exactly works, however, I guess that use `<img src="..." />` should be the best option to show up the image, instead `<h2>`.

Comment: so, after i saw that what i sent was the h2 tag but had tested the img tag and put my {{dataValues.Foto}} in "src =" and still it doesn't load the image that is saved in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put your blob as `src` of an image? In the code your putting it inside of an `h2` which is text, so it will print the blob text, because it's binary it looks like gibberish.

```
const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
const imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(dataValues.Foto);
const image = new Image();
image.addEventListener("onload", () => {
  //append the image in your body page
}
image.src = imageUrl;
```

try something like that

EDIT:
You can use the handlebars helpers to transform your blob to URL

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('blobToUrl', function(blob) {
   var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitULR;
   var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
   return imageUrl;
 });
```

then do this

```
<h1>Fotos:</h1>

{{#each fotos}}

    <img src="{{blobToUrl dataValues.Foto}}"></img>
    <hr>

{{/each}}
```

Comment: Hi! Do I have to try this on my handlebars?

Comment: Something like: <script> //your code </script> ?

Comment: I'm a little beginner in JS, sorry